Issue importing yoloV8 pose annotations, images load annotations do not
I am attempting to import images and annotations in YoloV8 pose format. The problem is when I try to upload my annotations the images load but there are no labeled points loaded.
I have my files organized in the same way as in this example:
https://docs.cvat.ai/docs/manual/advanced/formats/format-yolov8/#:~:text=YOLOv8%20is%20a%20format%20family,Pose
I have 355 images and in each image is roughly 50 sharks, each shark has 6 key points
my data.yaml looks like this:
data.yaml:
path:  ./ # dataset root dir
train: images/train/  # train images (relative to 'path')
Keypoint settings
kpt_shape: [6, 2]
Classes
names:
0: shark
my train.txt contains a row for each image that looks like:
images/train/frame1.png
The steps I am following right now are to

create a new task
add a single label called "shark" as I only have one class
I drag and drop my zipped folder that contains the images/train and labels/train subfolders, as well as the data.yaml and the train.txt
I click submit and open

The result is that the images will appear, but no labeled points or bounding boxes show up in the job.
Am I missing a step or doing something wrong? Happy to provide more info if needed.
Thanks in advance
-Darien
